# how to fetch the data from string input and save into datatable

Tags: asp.net, regex, string, c#-4.0

I want to fetch some data from string input like passenger name, base fare, total fare,commission, fop. All this field, I am showing in below image.  All this field, I want to store in data table. column name is:- passenger name, base fare, total fare,commission, fop.

this is my string input:-

```
string request= @"TST00009 DCA1S211E RH/07FEB F N LD 13FEB13 OD SANSAN SI                     
T-E                                                                             
FXP/R,U                                                                         
3.MACDORMAN/SAM CORBIN (CHD)                                                 
1   SAN BA  272 N 24JUN  825P OK NHXUQCNJ CH     24JUN24JUN 1PC                
2 O LHR BA  273 N 07AUG  325P OK NHXUQCNJ CH     07AUG07AUG 1PC                
 SAN                                                                        
FARE  U USD     492.00                                                          
TX001 X USD   458.00YQAC TX002 X USD     5.50YCAE TX003 X USD    17.20USAP      
TX004 X USD    17.20USAS TX005 X USD     5.00XACO TX006 X USD     7.00XYCR      
TX007 X USD     2.50AYSE TX008 X USD   105.61GBAD TX009 X USD    62.66UBAS      
TX010 X USD     4.50XF                                                          
TOTAL   USD    1177.17                                                          
GRAND TOTAL USD    1177.17                                                      
SAN BA LON M/BT NHXUQCNJ/CH BA SAN M/BT NHXUQCNJ/CH END                         
ROE1.000000 XF SAN4.5                                                          

BT1195364*BA *FM0.00                                                            

40.FE BA ONLY/NONREF/NONEND SEE GGAIRBAGUSA -BG:BA                             
45.FM *M*0.00A                                                                 
46.FP CHECK";
```

[image]

Comment: actually I am making application for flight availability so I got this type of input. I want to show this input on grid view for customer convenience.

Comment: I showed all necessary field in image which I want.

Comment: So, you want to find values that come after "FXP/R,U", "FARE U USD", "GRAND TOTAL USD", "45.FM", and "46.FP"? Can you simply search for those?

Comment: yes, exactly can you help me in this regard's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you'd be well-served to learn more about basic regular expressions.
[Regular-Expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) is one of my favorite resources. That said, hopefully this is a helpful start.

---

It might be cleaner to grab each piece individually rather than one single expression. Something like this:

```
Match m1 = Regex.Match(request, @"FXP/R,U\s+(.+?) \(CHD\)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
string name = m1.Groups[1].Value;

Match m2 = Regex.Match(request, @"FARE  U USD\s+(\d+\.\d{2})");
string fare = m2.Groups[1].Value;

Match m3 = Regex.Match(request, @"GRAND TOTAL USD\s+(\d+\.\d{2})");
string total = m3.Groups[1].Value;

Match m4 = Regex.Match(request, @"45\.FM (\S+)");
string commission = m4.Groups[1].Value;

Match m5 = Regex.Match(request, @"46\.FP (\S+)");
string fop = m5.Groups[1].Value;
```

If you really want, you could probably manage to do it in one, but it's kind of messy-looking:

```
string pattern = @"FXP/R,U\s+(?<name>.+?) \(CHD\).*FARE  U USD\s+(?<fare>\d+\.\d{2}).*GRAND TOTAL USD\s+(?<total>\d+\.\d{2}).*45\.FM (?<commission>\S+).*46\.FP (?<FOP>\S+)";

Match m = Regex.Match(request, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", m.Groups["name"]);
Console.WriteLine("Fare: {0}", m.Groups["fare"]);
Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", m.Groups["total"]);
Console.WriteLine("Commission: {0}", m.Groups["commission"]);
Console.WriteLine("FOP: {0}", m.Groups["FOP"]);
```

Working example of this: http://ideone.com/0bHUW9

You may have to adjust these patterns slightly. They work for your given example, but I made some assumptions about how they match (for example, it assumes that "commission" and "FOP" don't contain spaces). Hope that helps.